# SQL to list tables a's associated data from table b

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, sqlite

Given People (table: contacts) that have Phone Numbers (table: phones),

How do I write an SQL query (Sqlite3, postgres, or MySQL) to show each person and all of their phone numbers?

```
 Table: contacts      Table: Phones
 id  name             id  phone_number    contact_id
 1   Ashok            1   (111) 123-1111  1
 2   Betty            2   (111) 123-2222  1
 3   Charles          3   (111) 123-3333  1
                      4   (111) 123-4444  1
                      5   (222) 456-1111  2
                      6   (222) 456-2222  2
                      7   (333) 789-1111  3
                      8   (333) 789-2222  3
                      9   (333) 789-3333  3
```

I want the output to be:

```
Name    Phones
Ashok   (111) 123-1111 (111) 123-2222 (111) 123-3333 (111) 123-4444
Betty   (222) 456-1111 (222) 456-2222 
Charles (333) 789-1111 (333) 789-2222 (333) 789-3333
```

If I do a join:

```
SELECT      c.name, p.phone_number
FROM        contacts as c
INNER JOIN  phones as p
ON          c.id = p.contact_id
ORDER BY    c.name
```

the result is not what I want:

```
Name    Phone
Ashok   (111) 123-1111
Ashok   (111) 123-2222
Ashok   (111) 123-3333
Ashok   (111) 123-4444
Betty   (222) 456-1111
Betty   (222) 456-2222
Charles (333) 789-1111
Charles (333) 789-2222
Charles (333) 789-3333
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*MySQL* and *SQLite* both has `GROUP_CONCAT()` function :

```
SELECT c.name, GROUP_CONCAT(p.phone_number) AS Phones
FROM contacts AS c
INNER JOIN phones AS p ON c.id = p.contact_id
GROUP BY c.name
ORDER BY c.name;
```

In *PostgreSQL* you can use `array_to_string()` and `array_agg()` functions :

```
SELECT c.name, array_to_string(array_agg(p.phone_number), ',') AS Phones
FROM contacts AS c
INNER JOIN phones AS p ON c.id = p.contact_id
GROUP BY c.name
ORDER BY c.name;
```

Since *PostgreSQL* [9.0](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES) you can directly use `string_agg()` :

```
SELECT c.name, string_agg(p.phone_number, ',') AS Phones
FROM contacts AS c
INNER JOIN phones AS p ON c.id = p.contact_id
GROUP BY c.name
ORDER BY c.name;
```

Comment: SQLite also supports GROUP_CONCAT in some way https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#groupconcat

Comment: You might also want to use a custom `SEPARATOR` for `GROUP_CONCAT`:  `GROUP_CONCAT(p.phone_number SEPARATOR ' ')`.

Comment: PostgreSQL 9.0+ supports the function `string_agg()` which replaces `array_to_string(array_agg())` -> https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES